# Search bar connected to a Tableview with firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, search, firebase-realtime-database, uisearchbar

I have a search bar connected to a Tableview and I don't know how to make it work!
The table view is a table view of "Memories". memories have title, user id, body and I want it too be able to search by the Title.
The thing is that I'm working with firebase and I don't really know how to search in the specific memories of a specific user and how to bring it all from Firebase.

I tried so many code lines and nothing's work. I need help!

```
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseAuth
import FirebaseDatabase

class MemoryViewController: UIViewController,UITableViewDelegate,UITableViewDataSource, UISearchBarDelegate, UISearchResultsUpdating {

    func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
        self.memories = Array.filter({ (array: String) -> Bool in

            if array.contains(searchController.searchBar.text!)
            {
                return true
            }
            else
            {
                return false
            }

        })

        self.resultController.tableView.reloadData()

    }
    var filteredArray = [Memory]()

    var searchController = UISearchController()
    var resultController = UITableViewController()

    @IBOutlet weak var tbl: UITableView!

    @IBOutlet weak var searchBar: UISearchBar!

    var memories : [Memory] = []

    var ref : DatabaseReference!
    let sref = Storage.storage().reference()

    var lastIndex : Int = 0
    var strMode : String = ""

    var filteredData = [String]()



    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {

        return memories.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
        let identifier = "iden"

        var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)

        if cell == nil
        {
            cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
        }

        let temp = memories[indexPath.row]
        cell?.textLabel?.text = temp.title
        cell?.imageView?.image = temp.image
        return cell!
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {

        return true

    }


    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {

        if editingStyle == .delete
        {
            let temp = self.memories[indexPath.row]

            self.memories.remove(at: indexPath.row)

            self.ref.child("MEmories/\(temp.key)").removeValue()

            tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .fade)
        }
    }


    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ref = Database.database().reference()
        let rightButton = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .add, target: self, action: #selector(MemoryViewController.barButtonItemClicked(_:)))

        self.navigationItem.setRightBarButton(rightButton, animated: true)
        // Do any additional setup after loading the view.

        self.loadMemories()

        self.searchController = UISearchController(searchResultsController: resultController)
        tbl.tableHeaderView = self.searchController.searchBar

        self.searchController.searchResultsUpdater = self

        self.resultController.tableView.delegate = self
        self.resultController.tableView.dataSource = self



    }

    @objc func barButtonItemClicked(_ sender:UIBarButtonItem)
    {
        print("+ clicked")
        let addMemoryViewController = self.storyboard?.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "AddMemoryViewController") as! AddMemoryViewController

        self.strMode = "newMemory"


        self.navigationController?.pushViewController(addMemoryViewController, animated: true)



    }


    func readFromNSUSerDefault()-> Memory

    {

        let d : UserDefaults = UserDefaults.standard

        let strTitle = d.object(forKey: "title") as? String

        let strBody = d.object(forKey: "body") as? String

        let strImageRef = d.object(forKey: "imageRef") as? String

        let uid = d.object(forKey: "uid") as? String

        let imageData = d.object(forKey: "imageData") as? Data

        let key = d.object(forKey: "key") as? String



        let m = Memory(title: strTitle!, body: strBody!, key: key!, uid: uid!, imageRef: strImageRef!)

        m.image = UIImage(data: imageData!)

        m.key = key!

        return m

    }

    override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {

        let d = UserDefaults.standard
        let newMemory = readFromNSUSerDefault()
        let userAdded = d.bool(forKey: "userAdded") //key new user = true
        let userEdited = d.bool(forKey: "userEdited")//key  user edited = true

        if self.strMode == "newMemory" &&  userAdded

        {
            self.memories.append(newMemory)
            self.tbl.reloadData()
        }

        else if self.strMode == "edit" && userEdited
        {
            memories[lastIndex] = newMemory
            self.tbl.reloadData()
        }


        d.set(false, forKey: "userAdded")
        d.set(false, forKey: "userEdited")

        d.synchronize()

        self.strMode = " "


    }

    func loadMemories()

    {

        self.ref.child("MEmories").queryOrderedByKey().observe(.value, with: {

            snapShot in

            if let dict = snapShot.value as? NSDictionary

            {

                for d in (dict as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)!

                {

                    let title = d.value["title"] as?String

                    let body = d.value["body"] as? String

                    let uid = d.value["uid"] as? String

                    let imageRef = d.value["imageRef"] as? String



                    let m = Memory(title: title!, body: body!, uid: uid!,imageRef:imageRef!)

                    m.key = d.key

                    let tempImageRef = self.sref.child(m.imageRef)



                    tempImageRef.getData(maxSize: 1*1024*1024, completion: {(data,error) in



                        if error == nil

                        {

                            if let imageData = data

                            {

                                m.image = UIImage(data: imageData)

                                self.memories.append(m)

                                self.tbl.reloadData()

                            }

                        }

                    })

                }



            }//end of if

            self.ref.child("MEmories").removeAllObservers()



        })

    }

    override func prepare(for segue: UIStoryboardSegue, sender: Any?) {

        if let identifier = segue.identifier

        {

            if identifier == "goToEdit"

            {

                let indexPath = self.tbl.indexPathForSelectedRow

                let addMemoryViewController = segue.destination as! AddMemoryViewController

                self.strMode = "edit"

                self.lastIndex = (indexPath?.row)!

                addMemoryViewController.mode = self.strMode

                addMemoryViewController.current = memories[(indexPath?.row)!]

            }

        }

    }

}
```

Comment: i need to change this line:  self.memories = Array.filter({ (array: String) so it will check the TITLE of the memory and not just  the MEMORY

Comment: You've got two questions in one; how to query Firebase Realtime Database, then how to filter that data. It's really too broad to have both questions addressed. But to get started we need to know if you want to filter in code or filter in firebase, and what process do  you want to use for filtering? Enter a string and filter based on that string or do a character by character filter. Once we know that and you have a solution, using that within your searchBox and/or tableView is another question.

Answer (score 0):

You should store filtered values in filteredArray and use that array in table view data delegate, datasource methods

Store all values of memories array to filteredArray array in loadMemories method

```
if let dict = snapShot.value as? NSDictionary
{
    for d in (dict as? Dictionary<String,AnyObject>)!
    {
       //append in memories
    }
    self.filteredArray = self.memories
    self.tbl.reloadData()
}//end of if
```

Use filteredArray array in table view delegate datasource methods

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return filteredArray.count
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "iden"
    var cell : UITableViewCell? = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath)
    if cell == nil
    {
        cell = UITableViewCell(style: UITableViewCell.CellStyle.default, reuseIdentifier: identifier)
    }
    let temp = filteredArray[indexPath.row]
    cell?.textLabel?.text = temp.title
    cell?.imageView?.image = temp.image
    return cell!
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCell.EditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete
    {
        let temp = self.filteredArray[indexPath.row]
        self.filteredArray.remove(at: indexPath.row)
        if let index = self.memories.firstIndex(where: { $0.title == temp.title }) {
            self.memories.remove(at: index)
        }
        self.ref.child("MEmories/\(temp.key)").removeValue()
        tableView.deleteRows(at: [indexPath as IndexPath], with: .fade)
    }
}
```

In updateSearchResults method filter the memories array by comparing searchBar text with Memory objects title

```
func updateSearchResults(for searchController: UISearchController) {
    if searchController.searchBar.text!.isEmpty {
        self.filteredArray = self.memories
    } else {
        self.filteredArray = self.memories.filter({
            $0.title.localizedCaseInsensitiveContains(searchController.searchBar.text!)
        })
    }
    self.resultController.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: First of all, thank u so much! did you mean that when i use filteredArray array in table view delegate datasource methods it will be instead of using memories array there? because i need memories there to give the specific user his specific memories...

Comment: Yes. Use filteredArray array in table view delegate datasource methods instead of using memories array. And filteredArray is just copy of memories array. So there will be no problem. try it

Comment: sorry, now it doesn't show memories in the TableView at all. probably because i replaced memories array with filteredArray array in table view delegate datasource methods. any ideas? :)

Comment: @ABM did you add `self.filteredArray = self.memories self.tbl.reloadData()` in `loadMemories` method as I've mentioned?

Comment: yeah... do you know what happened?

Comment: did you not change memories into filteredArray intentionally in this line code?: self.memories.remove(at: index).

Comment: @ABM I removed the value from filteredArray array and removed from memories array in next line

Comment: oh... so do u know what can i do? i just uploaded here the updated code so it will be easier for you to see the changes

Comment: This is good answer however, it's unclear of the OP want to filter in code or in Firebase. If they have a large dataset, there's a good chance that would overload the device using this code. Also, I see this answer contains older ObjC objects, like NSDictionary. It would be cool to have it be a Swifty answer. One other thing to note is that Dictionaries are unordered so looping through them to display will be showing the data unordered.

Comment: i want to filter in code by the Title of  the memory and I am still stuck... any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on a comment, this question is not directly related to Firebase but the original poster is asking this

> i want to filter in code by the Title of the memory and I am still
>   stuck... any ideas? – ABM

So, here's a complete example of how to filter in code by title of the memory.

Let's start with a simple class to hold a memory and it's title

```
class MemoryClass {
    var title = ""
    init(withTitle: String) {
        self.title = withTitle
    }
}
```

Then we'll build an array, which would be used as for example, a tableView dataSource

```
let m0 = MemoryClass(withTitle: "Gone Fishing")
let m1 = MemoryClass(withTitle: "Wedding")
let m2 = MemoryClass(withTitle: "France Vacation")
let m3 = MemoryClass(withTitle: "Italy Vacation")

let memoriesArray = [m0, m1, m2, m3]
```

and then the code to find a memory by title. In this case, we want to find the memory that has a title of 'Wedding'

```
let memoryTitleToFind = "Wedding"
let filteredArray = memoriesArray.filter { $0.title == memoryTitleToFind }
```

and to verify that memory was found, let's iterate over the found memories. Keep in mind if there are several memories titled 'Wedding', then it will filter all of them into the filtered Array

```
for foundMemory in filteredArray {
    print(foundMemory.title)
}
```

and the output showing the filtered results is

```
Wedding
```

I created a simple MemoryClass for this answer and in your question you note there are other properties

> memories have title, user id, body and I want it too be able to search
>   by the Title

So those could be added to the class and filtered in the same fashion.

Comment: thank u some much, but the thing that I'm stuck with is that the array of memories is dynamic. the user can create new memories or delete memories, so working with the firebase is what it is all about. thank u so much though.

Comment: @ABM That's not what your comment states or what your question asks. You asked *how to filter in code* and this is the solution to do that. It would work for 'dynamic' data as the memoriesArray would be updated whenever there's a change to your Firebase data. If you are asking something else, please update and clarify the question as to what you really mean.